# MS Access 2010 Form with check box per record

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a form that allows my audit team to help identify transactions that need further investigation.

Is the following is possible? If so what would be the best method for accomplishing this?  I would like to have a check box in a form for each record that is returned from a query.  That check box would then be used to identify records that would be appended to another table.

I've done this in the past for forms linked to temporary tables; however, since this form is linked to a query I think I'm having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the checkbox to the form and use some VBA code to insert all those rows from the query into another table that have the checkbox checked (`Forms!MyForm!myCb = True`)